# looping not happening in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want a carousel-type looping where 1 image comes, hides and another does the same and so on. the problem is that i want this to loop infinitely, which is not happening.

```
  $(function(){



 //alert(j)
  var j=-1;

 setInterval(function(){

  console.log('hi');
 if(j>=$(".carousel .item").length){
 console.log("hut");
 j = -1;
 }
 while(j<$(".carousel .item").length){


    j++;
console.log("i: "+j);
    $(".carousel .item").eq(j-1).hide();
        $(".carousel .item").eq(j).show(function(){
            alert("hiii");
        },200,"linear");

    //console.log(j);   


 }
 j=-1;
 //console.log(j)

 },1200);



  })
```

html:

```
  <div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">India</div>
  <div class="item">china</div>
  <div class="item">Australia</div>

  </div>
```

css:

```
  .carousel .item{display: none;}
```

i resetted the j variable after the while loop but no effect. Please help. Thanks in advance.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fj2r0req/

Answer (score 1):

Here is working script

```
var j;
var noOfCar;
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    j = 0;
    noOfCar = $(".carousel .item").length - 1;
    $(".carousel .item").eq(0).show();
    setInterval(function () {
        if (j < noOfCar) {
            $(".carousel .item").eq(j).hide();
            j += 1;
            $(".carousel .item").eq(j).show();
        } else {
            console.log("Inside else");
            $(".carousel .item").eq(j).hide();
            $(".carousel .item").eq(0).show();
            j = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks aravind so much, it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the part

```
$(".carousel .item").eq(j).show(function(){
        alert("hiii");
    },200,"linear");
```

Otherwise you could use a recursive function like below:

```
var nbItems = $(".carousel .item").length;
var startingItem = 0;

function cycle(index, nbItems) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".carousel .item").eq(index-1).hide();
         $(".carousel .item").eq(index).show();

        index++;

        if (index >= nbItems) {
            index = 0;
        }

        cycle(index, nbItems);
    }, 1000);
}

cycle(startingItem, nbItems);
```